# Unable to getState in redux actions

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am unable to getState within my redux actions.js. Following code doesn't post, only prints in console 'i am out!' and throws no errors:

Test.jsx:

```
...
import { testPost } from './actions';

...
onSubmit (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    testPost({
            todo: 'test'
        });
}
```

actions.jsx:

```
export function testPost (todo) {
    console.log('i am out!');

    return function (dispatch, getState) {      
    console.log('i am in!');
    let id = getState().test.id;
    return fetch(`url`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            id: id,
            todo: todo
        })
    });         
}

}
```

Note that if I comment out following line and hardcode id, it posts well:

```
return function (dispatch, getState) {
```

**Also, please let me know if it's right expecting 'I am in!' to be printed in the above sample code.**

Comment: You need `redux-thunk` or some other suitable middleware. You'll also need to `dispatch` your `testPost` action in the first place.

Comment: @BenSmith, I am totally new to react/redux. Any link or sample that can clarify how do I dispatch this?

Comment: btw, i am trying to use react-redux, if that's what you meant by the middleware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the id you need in to your action creator (*testPost*), that way your actions don't need to know about the state.

For example:

```
  export function testPost(todo) {
  console.log('i am out!');
  return function(dispatch, id) {
    return fetch(`url`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        id: id,
        todo: todo
      })
    });
  }
}
```

**Edit**

I'd look at the two (free) online courses I noted in my comment, the second of which has a section on retrieving data, but I'd get to understand redux (actions, reducers and their plumbing) first in a simpler use case before fetching data.

Comment: you mean, the same as testPost(todo, id) right? I know of that way. just trying to learn how jsx/actions/reducers work together. any help?

Comment: Ah, really sorry. You can't get any better than: https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux followed by https://egghead.io/courses/building-react-applications-with-idiomatic-redux

Comment: great! thanks a lot. any recommended link for react that you familiar with?

Comment: Try https://egghead.io/courses/react-fundamentals but I'm not sure this one is entirely free (the first two I mentioned are, at least if you register). The react docs (https://facebook.github.io/react/) are very good and hopefully you can find something helpful on YouTube. Good luck and happy learning!